# game character class design, inheritance or composition?

Tags: java

I am trying to create the character class for a game.

About the character class:
-It has different characters, for example warrior, shooter, king.
-Each has different properties for example attack, defense.

My question here is should I use Inheritance or composition?
I have a Character Class, then should I create warrior class and extends character class or should I just put an identifier like String ID ="Warrior" in the Character class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What I would do is to use inheritance for the classes + Interfaces if there is an option for a combination of properties (for example, if you have a WarriorKing class).

If you want to enjoy the properties of both types in case of something like WarriorKing you can do something like that:

```
class Character { ... }

interface Warrior {...}

interface King {...}

abstract class KingImpl extends Character implements King

abstract class WarriorImpl extends Character implements Warrior
```

And then you combine everything:

```
class WarriorKing extends Character implements Warrior, King {
    private King kingImpl;
    private Warrior warriorImpl;

    public WarriorKing() {
        kingImpl = new KingImpl();
        warriorImpl = new WarriorImpl();

    }
```

Now lets say you have a method `kill()` in the Warrior interface which needs to be implemented by each implementing class (WarriorKing must implement it), and is already implemented in the abstract WarriorImpl class, you can do something like:

```
class WarriorKing extends Character implements Warrior, King {
    private King kingImpl;
    private Warrior warriorImpl;

    public WarriorKing() {
        kingImpl = new KingImpl();
        warriorImpl = new WarriorImpl();

    }

    public void kill() {
      this.warriorImpl.kill()
    }

 }
```

This way you enjoy all the worlds by having everything implemented once, having a modular class design and you can enjoy any composition of characters you might need. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

The way I like doing it is to write out all of the properties and parameters of EVERY class you want to have. See what parameters are shared among the classes and decide how you want to approach it.

Since you already have a Character class, decide how different you want the actual sub-classes of Character to be.

What you can also do is use different [Interfaces](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html) for different classes. The interfaces will have the methods unique for the particular class.

Don't hesitate and just go for it, it doesn't really matter that much how you handle it, but Interfaces and Inheritance sure make your code easier to understand. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution in terms of modular design and (later) complexity would be to extend the base class as you can use Interfaces for only "the warrior" or only "shooter" etc.

And think of adding different methods or properties you want to set for only a specific char (now or maybe later).

Hope this helps.

Best,

Answer (score 0):

If all characters share certain properties, then I would have a Character class with said properties and have each specific kind of character would extend Character and add their specific properties.

Comment: But then you would end up with duplicate code if two or more classes had the same (overlapping but not subsetted) extensions.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by extensions.  There should be no duplicate code if all common 'traits' are accounted for in the Character class.  Anything that is specific only to a certain type of character, say, a warrior, would be in its class.

Answer (score 0):

String id = "Warrior" sounds like "stringly typed programming" and you should avoid it.

The rule of thumb is that class hierarchy shouldn't be deep (no more than 3 or 4 levels).

I'd define a base class (Character) and **some** derived class (Warrior, Wizard, etc) but wouldn't go any deeper:

- Character < Warrior < AxeWarrior
- Character < Wizard < LightWizard
- Character < Wizard < EvilWizard

It looks that your characters do have different attributes, but has essentially the same behavior (Attack, Defense, etc). But the means of attacking and defending are different (a Warrior would hash and slash, a Wizard would spell a magic). This is a good candidate for inheritance and polymorphism.

Answer (score 0):

If the characters have different values for the same properties then you shouldn't create different classes, but if warrior as a whole can do things/has different properties that the others can't, then yes.
For example: If the warriors have a different value for the property "strength" than magicians then in that case there is no need to create the subclasses for each as they are conceptually the same. However if magicians can fly then yes you should.